# Rails - Delete all Records that Meet a Condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do you write in the Rails way?
I have a model - Managers.
I want to delete all records from Managers that meet the condition that manager_level is 5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I think it is better to use destroy instead of delete

> because destroy will delete current object record from db and also its
>   associated children record from db (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22757656/5452072)

Also delete will skip callbacks, but destroy doesn't.

```
Manager.where(:manager_level => 5).destroy_all
```

Comment: Definitely valid, but keep in mind: "Destroys the records matching conditions by instantiating each record and calling its destroy method." (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all) This could be very slow for large result sets.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about keeping models consistent and stuff.

Comment: @MurifoX - Can you explain why you think destroy is better than delete? Not necessarily disagreeing, but it would help make your answer more complete.

Comment: @PhilDD I had the same question and I think the answer is missing the reasoning on why to use destroy_all, not delete_all. I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22757533/5452072

Comment: Both destroy_all and delete_all have their place. When you want to delete 100k records quickly and you know that there are no callbacks or referential integrity issues, destroy_all takes forever for no benefit while delete_all does what you want quickly. When you want to cleanly delete 100 records and do all the Rails cleanup for them, destroy_all is what you want.

Answer (score 36):

Try this:

```
Manager.delete_all(manager_level: 5)
```

Comment: 1. I need to use a variable to specify what to delete.
2. The table does not have an index, it is a connector table between 2 other tables.

Comment: Didn't work for me. There was an error due to referential integrity.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, as other queries try to SELECT before DELETING -- leading to performance problems on large datasets.

Comment: passing conditions to `delete_all/destroy_all` has been [removed in rails 5.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27503/files#diff-eb992cfe9de67b368e9d3736ab1388d8L506).

Answer (score 21):

This should work:

```
Manager.where(:manager_level => 5).delete_all
```

Note: This will not remove dependent records.

Answer (score 9):

After Rails 5.1., We cannot pass conditions to `delete_all/destroy_all` method

```
Manager.where(:manager_level => 5).delete_all
```

> This will run multiple queries to delete each record

But in Rails 6, we can use delete_by to delete using condition,

```
Manager.delete_by(manager_level: 5)
```

> This will run single delete query
>
> `delete from managers where manager_level = 5`

Comment: I am not sure the Rails 6 model.delete_by(cond) is any faster than the model.where(cond).delete_all approach. You can see the implementation of delete_by on its original branch appears to just be syntactic sugar.      https://github.com/abhaynikam/rails/commit/5c8d4c3466cbfa850a89f718ec358ed3a352c34e#diff-18a561656864ea240daf46bdb1f50faace49f9ef74b90bcf667d9bbb17fce084R532