# Difference between Destroy and Delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy, delete-row

What is the difference between

`@model.destroy` and `@model.delete`

For example:

```
Model.find_by(col: "foo").destroy_all
//and
Model.find_by(col: "foo").delete_all
```

Does it really matter if I use the one or the other?

Answer (score 361, accepted):

Basically `destroy` runs any callbacks on the model while `delete` doesn't.

From the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org):

- [`ActiveRecord::Persistence.delete`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete)

  > Deletes the record in the database and freezes this instance to reflect that no changes should be made (since they can't be persisted). Returns the frozen instance.
  >
  > The row is simply removed with an SQL DELETE statement on the record's primary key, and no callbacks are executed.
  >
  > To enforce the object's before_destroy and after_destroy callbacks or any :dependent association options, use #destroy.
- [`ActiveRecord::Persistence.destroy`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy)

  > Deletes the record in the database and freezes this instance to reflect that no changes should be made (since they can't be persisted).
  >
  > There's a series of callbacks associated with destroy. If the before_destroy callback return false the action is cancelled and destroy returns false. See ActiveRecord::Callbacks for further details.

Comment: Hello @user740584 - thanks for your answer. What do you mean by "runs any callbacks on the model"?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon he means ActiveRecord::Callbacks: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html. One such callback is `model#before_destroy` which can be used to halt the final `destroy()` call under certain conditions.

Comment: Now I know why the acts_as_paranoid is not working in delete since its directly going thru the Model. You better use the destroy if you wanted to work the soft delete.

Answer (score 140):

`delete` will only delete current object record from db but not its associated children  records from db.

`destroy` will delete current object record from db and also its associated children  record from db.

**Their use really matters:**

If your multiple parent objects share common children objects, then calling `destroy` on specific parent object will delete children objects which are shared among other multiple parents.

Comment: Brilliant answer. thank you. i would add that the terminology as i understand it is that the children are "killed". brutal infanticide.

Comment: In most cases in production you want to use 'destroy'

Comment: No this is not necessary.

Comment: I think the word you should be using for `destroy` is **descendants**, not _children_: according to the documentation, destroy "creates a new object from the attributes, and then calls destroy on it." https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveRecord%2FRelation:destroy

Answer (score 17):

When you invoke `destroy` or `destroy_all` on an `ActiveRecord` object, the `ActiveRecord` 'destruction' process is initiated, it analyzes the class you're deleting, it determines what it should do for dependencies, runs through validations, etc.

When you invoke `delete` or `delete_all` on an object, `ActiveRecord` merely tries to run the `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE conditions` query against the db, performing no other `ActiveRecord`-level tasks.

Answer (score 7):

Example:

```
Class User
  has_many :contents, dependent: :destroy
end

user = User.last
user.delete -> only user
user.destroy -> delete user , and contents of user
```

`delete` will delete current record from db (No callback)

`destroy` will delete current record and associated record (Has callback)

The same with `delete_all` and `destroy_all`

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a major difference between the two methods
Use delete_all if you want records to be deleted quickly without model callbacks being called

If you care about your models callbacks then use destroy_all

From the official docs

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class

> destroy_all(conditions = nil) public
>
> Destroys the records matching conditions by instantiating each record
>   and calling its destroy method. Each object’s callbacks are executed
>   (including :dependent association options and
>   before_destroy/after_destroy Observer methods). Returns the collection
>   of objects that were destroyed; each will be frozen, to reflect that
>   no changes should be made (since they can’t be persisted).
>
> Note: Instantiation, callback execution, and deletion of each record
>   can be time consuming when you’re removing many records at once. It
>   generates at least one SQL DELETE query per record (or possibly more,
>   to enforce your callbacks). If you want to delete many rows quickly,
>   without concern for their associations or callbacks, use delete_all
>   instead.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of answers already; wanted to jump on with a bit more.

[docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Delete+or+destroy-3F):

> For has_many, destroy and destroy_all will always call the destroy method of the record(s) being removed so that callbacks are run. However delete and delete_all will either do the deletion according to the strategy specified by the :dependent option, or if no :dependent option is given, then it will follow the default strategy. The default strategy is to do nothing (leave the foreign keys with the parent ids set), except for has_many :through, where the default strategy is delete_all (delete the join records, without running their callbacks).

The `delete` verbage works differently for `ActiveRecord::Association.has_many` and `ActiveRecord::Base`. For the latter, delete will execute `SQL DELETE` and bypass all validations/callbacks. The former will be executed based on the `:dependent` option passed into the association. However, during testing, I found the following side effect where callbacks were only ran for `delete` and not `delete_all`

`dependent: :destroy` Example:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :children,
     before_remove: -> (_) { puts "before_remove callback" },
     dependent: :destroy
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :parent

   before_destroy -> { puts "before_destroy callback" }
end

> child.delete                            # Ran without callbacks
Child Destroy (99.6ms)  DELETE FROM "children" WHERE "children"."id" = $1  [["id", 21]]

> parent.children.delete(other_child)     # Ran with callbacks
before_remove callback
before_destroy callback
Child Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "children" WHERE "children"."id" = $1  [["id", 22]]

> parent.children.delete_all              # Ran without callbacks
Child Destroy (1.0ms)  DELETE FROM "children" WHERE "children"."parent_id" = $1  [["parent_id", 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically "delete" sends a query directly to the database to delete the record. In that case Rails doesn't know what attributes are in the record it is deleting nor if there are any callbacks (such as `before_destroy`).

The "destroy" method takes the passed id, fetches the model from the database using the "find" method, then calls destroy on that. This means the callbacks are triggered.

You would want to use "delete" if you don't want the callbacks to be triggered or you want better performance. Otherwise (and most of the time) you will want to use "destroy".