# RSpec matcher for ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have Rails 4 Application with TravelNotes. Travel notes has 3 kind of statuses: draft, published, archived.
If the status is draft, then it can be deleted otherwise not.

In the TravelNote-Model:

```
  before_destroy :check_for_draft

  def check_for_draft
    if status == 'draft'
      delete
    else
      errors.add(:scope, 'Only drafts can be deleted')
      return false
    end
  end
```

And i use RSpec for testing:

```
it "should delete a travel note if its status is draft"  do
  expect{ draft.destroy! }.to change{ TravelNote.count }.by(-1)
end


it "should not delete a travel note if its status is published or archived" do
  expect{ published.destroy! }.to_not change{ TravelNote.count }
```

When i run the test the draft-deleting-test passes but for published-deleting-test i get:

```
Failures:
  1) TravelNote delete should not delete a travel note if its status is published or archived
 Failure/Error: expect{ published.destroy! }.to_not change{ TravelNote.count }
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed:
   ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed
```

Obviously the code is working and only travel notes with other statuses than draft can be deleted.

How can i turn the Failure-Message  ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed to green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just had to remove the bang in destroy! to get the test pass:

```
it "should not delete a travel note if its status is published or archived" do
  expect{ published.destroy }.to_not change{ TravelNote.count }
  expect{ archived.destroy }.to_not change{ TravelNote.count }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

1. You are using the `bang!` version of `destroy!` which coerces any `before_destroy` callback from returning `false` to `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed`.
2. You are using `delete` in your method and `destroy!` in your tests.  `delete` doesn't invoke the callbacks - see [Difference between Destroy and Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757450/difference-between-destroy-and-delete)
3. You shouldn't call `delete` or `destroy` of `self` inside the `before_destroy` callback.  Not returning `false` will cause the original `destroy` action to work.

@Felipe posted the link to `destroy`, you should also look at the link to `destroy!`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy-21

which states

> There's a series of callbacks associated with destroy!. If the before_destroy callback return false the action is cancelled and destroy! raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed. See ActiveRecord::Callbacks for further details.

Comment: To be clear, you can `delete` or `destroy` other related records, but you shouldn't `self.delete` since the callback does that for you

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
expect{ published.destroy! }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed)
```

**For more information**:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/destroy%21

Comment: Thanks Felipe, your approach is working. But after removing the bang in destroy! the test passes, too. I'm not sure if this is the rspec-way to check but i stick with "to_not change".