# ERROR: delete on table violates foreign key constraint. Key id is still referenced from table (many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sublimetext2, better-errors-gem

I'm working with Rails and PostgreSQL and have a basic one-to-many relationship going on, one `Auction` has many `Bid`s. However when I try and delete an auction (that has bids present) I get the following error:

> ERROR: update or delete on table "auctions" violates foreign key
>   constraint "fk_rails_43e9021cbf" on table "bids". DETAIL: Key(id)=(1)
>   is still referenced from table "bids".

Deleting auctions with no bids gives no error.

The part that confuses me is that inside my `Auction` model, I have:

```
has_many :bids, dependent: :destroy
```

[image: Error Screen Shot (better_error gem)]

Since I have a dependent destroy clause, why am I still getting this error?

**EDIT:** I've tried dropping the whole DB, then recreating/re-migrating everything - still get the same error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My issue was that i am using `@auction.delete` (visible in the screenshot I posted) when trying to remove a record.

Delete will ignore any callbacks I have in place. So even though I have a dependent destroy clause, it is not being called - hence Rails is throwing an error. If/When I changed the code to read `@auction.destroy`, the call-back got invoked and it solved the problem.

Reference:
[Difference between Destroy and Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757450/difference-between-destroy-and-delete)

Comment: Great spot! This was my exact issue!

Answer (score 49):

From **Rails v4.2** you can do this:

*Create a migration to update the foreign keys*

**`20160321165946_update_foreign_key.rb`**

```
class UpdateForeignKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # remove the old foreign_key
    remove_foreign_key :posts, :users

    # add the new foreign_key
    add_foreign_key :posts, :users, on_delete: :cascade
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks , i fixed that typo.

Comment: How would I do this in the initial reference creation migration? For example, do I do this: ```ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :job_queries, :user, foreign_key: true, on_delete: :cascade
  end
end```

Comment: (From a Rails 5.1.4 perspective) I get the sense that foreign_key is a database-level setting whereas dependent: :delete_all is a model-level setting. If we have a foreign_key set in the database (check your schema.rb), dependent: :delete_all will not suffice, we need on_delete: :cascade at the database level too. I found this article helpful: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/10/04/rails-active-record-postgres-optimizing-deletions/.

Comment: This is a nice fix, and solves the issue for me... but... why do we have to resort getting the DB to clean up when we've told Rails to do this via `dependent: :destroy`? I've not seen this before on other code bases and yet on my current one I am having to use a ton of these!

Answer (score 24):

Are you using `delete` or `destroy` to remove the objects? I think you are using `delete` and you want to use `destroy`

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Delete+or+destroy-3F

Comment: thanks ! switching to destroy instead of delete fixed the problem!

Answer (score 12):

Are you by chance using the [paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) gem or something like it?

If you are `bids` are `paranoid` and `auctions` are not, you may run into this error.

This would happen because when rails executes the `dependent: destroy`, it would soft-deletes the bids, but they still actually exist in the DB (they just have the `deleted_at` column set).  Therefore, the foreign key constraint would fail.

Comment: Nope wasn't using gems, see my update with solution/explanation

Answer (score 4):

Your error is from the database not rails. You need to delete the bids first in your app or change the foreign key constraint in the db to cascade the delete

Comment: Ive tried "rake db:drop" then re-created the database and re-ran the migration files... still get the same error!

Comment: If there's a foreign key in there, all that would do is drop it and recreate it. You need to search the script(s) see if it in there, on examine the db itself.

Comment: I too have this problem, and see that its the DB raising the error, but why isn't rails deleting the dependant records first? The OP and I have the model constraint `dependent: :destroy`.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are good, but don't mention that sometimes **you want to leave the dependent record, but nullify the foreign key**.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Note that this will require ensuring the foreign key column in the database table has null: true

I'm not positive, but you may also need to add ***optional: true*** to the belongs to association defined in the dependent model.

Answer (score 1):

Marc Busqué has [a very good article](http://waiting-for-dev.github.io/blog/2015/02/03/rails-rescue-from-all-foreign-key-violations-at-once/) about this problem that might can help.

"When ActiveRecord encounters a foreign key violation, it raises an ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey exception. Even if in its documentation it just says that it is raised when a record cannot be inserted or updated because it references a non-existent record, the fact is that it is also used in the case we are interested."

With that and a rescue_from we can just add to ApplicationController or to a controller concern:

```
rescue_from 'ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey' do
  # Flash and render, render API json error... whatever
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/jenseng/immigrant/issues/31#issuecomment-364336428) explain how to fix it.

To solve this, you probably want to modify your has_many :comments association in your User model to have a dependent option. Some possibilities:

- has_many :comments, dependent: :delete_all - just automatically delete them when the user is deleted
- has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy - like above, but call #destroy on each comment instead of just deleting directly in the db
- has_many :comments, dependent: :nullify - don't delete comments when the user is deleted, just null out their user_id column

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many for more information

Answer (score -2):

A really simple explanation: the associated table contains at least 1 record joined to the record in the table you're trying to destroy.

To fix this, add `dependent: :destroy` (assuming a User has_many Posts)

```
has_many :post, dependent: :destroy
```