# ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey error thrown when trying to delete a record that has a dependent record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have classes `Upload` and `Override`. `Override` `belongs_to :upload`, and each `Upload` `has_one :override`. When I try to call `destroy` on any `Upload` that does in fact have an `Override` associated with it, I get a fatal response in the console with this message:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "uploads" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_ae7fe83ba8" on table "overrides"
```

I have implemented both the foreign key migration approach a la [SUPER USER's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996773/error-delete-on-table-violates-foreign-key-constraint-key-id-is-still-referenc), as well as the `dependent: destroy` method from [Ricky Mason's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544693/cant-delete-object-due-to-foreign-key-constraint) (as in, `Upload` contains `has_one :override, dependent: :destroy`), and yet I still get the `ForeignKeyViolation` error.

How do I go about deleting a particular Upload record along with its dependent Override record?

EDIT:

Code for each model:

```
class Upload < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :override, dependent: :destroy
end


class Override < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :upload
end
```

Forgive me if I misunderstood what you needed as far as schema goes, but you can find my [schema results here](https://pastebin.com/R2c9LteG).

To reproduce the error, an `Override` object has to be associated with an `Upload` object. Afterwards, you need to call `.destroy` on that `Upload` object.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I was so focused on trying to effectively communicate my problem that I managed to completely forget to ask an actual question! Thanks, the question has been edited to reflect what I'm actually trying to do.

Comment: Show us the actual code. Your models, the schema and the exact steps to reproduce the error.

Comment: Hey Max, just updated the question to include the info you're looking for.