# Diff Btw Destroy and delete in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can somebody explain the diff btw delete and destroy in rails with examples?

```
article.destroy
```

> (0.2ms)  begin transaction
>   SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ?  [["id",
>   9]]
>   (84.5ms)  commit transaction
>
> => #

```
article.delete
```

> SQL (28.3ms)  DELETE FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = 10
>
> => #

basically both do the same task but I couldn't figure out the rollback part.How can I rollback in destroy and not in delete. Kindly take the burden of explaining it to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Destroy and Delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757450/difference-between-destroy-and-delete)

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "the rollback part."?

Answer (score -1):

Basically destroy runs any callbacks on the model while delete doesn't.

ActiveRecord::Persistance.delete

```
Deletes the record in the database and freezes this instance to reflect that no changes should be made (since they can't be persisted). Returns the frozen instance.

The row is simply removed with an SQL DELETE statement on the record's primary key, and no callbacks are executed.

To enforce the object's before_destroy and after_destroy callbacks or any :dependent association options, use #destroy.
```

ActiveRecord::Persistance.destroy

```
Deletes the record in the database and freezes this instance to reflect that no changes should be made (since they can't be persisted).

There's a series of callbacks associated with destroy. If the before_destroy callback return false the action is cancelled and destroy returns false. See ActiveRecord::Callbacks for further details.
```