# Rails: Use destroy action in model's method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to do some task before I destroy a user. I am doing a system for a network marketing company. I need to change the user of users. So this is what I did:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


    def delete_this_user
      some_actions
.
.
.
      self.destroy
end


end
```

the

`self.destroy` doesn't destroy the user from the database. Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: Does it not? It certainly should. What happens? (Eg is a delete sql query executed but rolled back?)

Answer (score 2):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def delete_this_user
    some_actions
    self.class.delete(id)
  end
end
```

**UPD** (thx @Rich):

[`delete`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete) will skip all callbacks, whereas [`destroy`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy) will trigger every associated callback.

Comment: Must be known that this will [skip all the callbacks etc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22757533/1143732)