# dependent destroy not working gives foreign key exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have an Account model that has one page table records when I'm trying to delete/destroy an account instance Activerecords gave me an exception `ForiegnKey` even I defined in the account model.

the error is:
`PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "accounts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_a01c5b1985" on table "pages" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "pages". : DELETE FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1`

Account.rb

```
has_one :page, dependent: :destroy
```

Please give me solution how can I achieve all dependent record also deleted/destroyed when a parent record is deleted without any exception.

Comment: Are you using `delete` or `destroy`? Only `destroy` runs the callbacks. See [Difference between Destroy and Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757450/difference-between-destroy-and-delete).

Comment: @jdno I tried both methods to delete object but unfortunately same error occurred.

Comment: Do you try to destroy account instance in the rails console? If yes, maybe you forgot to reload it after adding `dependent: :destroy`?

Comment: @Vasilisa yeah I tried in the console but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you save `account.rb`? Please, paste the code - how do you try to delete it?

Comment: @Vasilisa of course