# Deleting rails active records with delete_all/delete violates foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, cascading-deletes

I have an active record association setup with :dependent => :destroy, which works as intended.
Then I found out I need to use delete instead of destroy due to performance, so I just changed destroy to delete_all/delete depending on the association.

When I try to delete:

```
shop.shop_snapshots.completed.last.delete
```

I get the error message:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "shop_snapshots" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_c24b24adaf" on table "inventory_items"
```

But why is that - I believe I have the proper setup on the snapshot:

```
has_many :inventory_items, :dependent => :delete_all
```

and it worked for destroy, so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks
/Louise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Destroy and Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757450/difference-between-destroy-and-delete)

Comment: Not quite - it says "delete will only delete current object record from db but not its associated children records from db". That would mean that only my snapshot is deleted, and not the associated inventory_items, which explains the error message. Bu why does Rails support setting :dependent => :delete_all, if it cannot support cascade deletes on children - the ":dependent => :delete_all" would have no effect then?

Comment: if you call `destroy` instead of `delete` it will work, I am sure

Comment: Yes using `destroy` already works as I described - but I do not want to use `destroy` as I need the better performance provided by `delete`.

Comment: Please read the text linked in the first comment again: only `destroy` takes the `:dependent` association actions into account. `delete` can only offer better performance _because_ it skips callbacks and dependent asssociation checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Postgres you can use the CASCADE option on the foreign key itself.

> CASCADE specifies that when a referenced row is deleted, row(s)
>   referencing it should be automatically deleted as well.
>   - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ddl-constraints.html

This is usually setup when creating the table but you can add it to an exisiting table by removing and then re-adding the foreign key constraint:

```
class AddCascadeToOrderItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    remove_foreign_key :order_items, :orders
    add_foreign_key :order_items, :orders, on_delete: :cascade
  end

  def down
    remove_foreign_key :order_items, :orders
    add_foreign_key :order_items, :orders
  end
end
```

Since this is handled on the DB level no configuration is needed in your model.

```
has_many :inventory_items, dependent: :delete_all
```

Works as well and is the only option on peasant databases like MySQL but it will only be fired when you call `.destroy` and not `.delete` on the model that declares the association as its implemented as a model callback. For example:

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :inventory_items, dependent: :delete_all
end

store = Store.find(1)
store.destroy # triggers callbacks and will delete all assocatiated inventory_items
store.delete  # will not trigger callbacks
```

Comment: Ok thanks, your answer helped me a lot. A couple of follow-up questions: a) in the down method the remove and add methods should be switched right? b) ok I see the dependent: :delete_all works if I initiate it with destroy, but it does only work on "one level", i.e. any children order_items might have will not be deleted, because the callback is not triggered by the delete on order_items as you explain. For that reason I will need to use cascade on the foreign keys.

Comment: A) yes you're right - the order is wrong. B) yes. Also right. The associated records are removed with the `.delete_all` method which just creates a single SQL delete query and does not instanciate the models or call callbacks.

Comment: The advantage of cascade inte this case is that it cascades so the children and grandchildren will be deleted if you setup the foreign keys properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it on migration level.

Something like this:

```rb
create_table :childs do |t|
  t.references :parent, index: true, foreign_key: {on_delete: :cascade}
  t.string :name

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```