# Rails counter_cache on has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the [`counter_culture`](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) gem to cache my counts. Here are the models:

#### User model

```rb
has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
```

#### Membership model

```rb
has_many :authorables, dependent: :destroy
has_many :posts, through: :authorables
```

#### Post model

```rb
has_many :authorables, dependent: :destroy
has_many :authors, through: :authorables, source: :membership
```

#### Authorable model

```rb
belongs_to :membership
belongs_to :post

counter_culture :post, column_name: "authors_count"
```

As you can see, I am caching the `authors_count` on the `post` model.

When I update the post, `post.update(authors: [membership])` the counter increments by 1, but when I try and remove the authors `post.update(authors: [])`, the counter does not decrement.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: With the code unchanged, if I do `post.authors.find(1).destroy`, the `counter_cache` works as expected. But I do not understand why `post.update(authors: [])` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. You cannot use `post.update(authors: [])` and trigger callbacks.

[`counter_culture`](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture/blob/master/lib/counter_culture/extensions.rb#L94) gem that you provided builds its functionality on top of rails callbacks execution, I pointed in that url code which does it.

`post.update(authors: [])` this code doesn't trigger ActiveRecord callbacks.
Neither this one `post.authors.find(1).delete`.

So in order to trigger your callbacks and update `counter_cache` column, you will need to write some function that will resolve authors and trigger `destroy`

Consider this

```rb
some_conditions = { id: [1,2,3] }

post.authors.where(some_conditions).each(&:destroy)
```

For further reading you refer to this [well-described answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22757533/5347939) about ActiveRecord callbacks

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct. I created a method that runs when the number of authors persisted to the post does not match the number of authors to be persisted with the update action and it works as expected now.