# Remove all records from a certain id onwards in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I accidentally forgot to turn a scheduled task and added rows to a table that shouldn't be there.

I know the id from which I wish to remove rows. But how do you do it?

I've tried

```rb
Datum.where("id > 650").delete
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))
```

also

```
Datum.where("id > 650").destroy
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):5
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all delete_all vs destroy_all in a short comparison:

- delete_all: Will delete your data directly from the table without instantiating your ActiveRecord; Faster, but maybe not save depended on your model.
- destroy_all: Your ActiveRecord will be instantiating and your Callbacks, Cascade Deletes and so on will be performed. Slower, but save.

If you have a RecordSet you always have to perfrom delete/destroy_all because the methods delete/destroy are only for a single ActiveRecord.

Sources:

- https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all
- https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be with [`destroy_all`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12826036/5783745)

```rb
Datum.where("id > 650").destroy_all
  Datum Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "data".* FROM "data" WHERE (id > 650)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Datum Destroy (10.2ms)  DELETE FROM "data" WHERE "data"."id" = $1  [["id", 651]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Datum Destroy (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "data" WHERE "data"."id" = $1  [["id", 652]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Datum Destroy (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "data" WHERE "data"."id" = $1  [["id", 653]]
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
```

I suspect `destroy` doesn't work because it protecting against the small chance of a disaster when someone meant to delete one record but accidentally provided multiple

Comment: `destroy` is intended for one